# ping ignoring copy and paste of "http://"

Tags: browser, ping

Who does not often have the following problem?

You copy an URL from your Browser to paste in on the console to use it for ping (or other commands) that don't accept a hostname or ip with a leading "http(s)://"

How do you get rid of this the easiest? Or just don't copy it from your URL-Bar?

```
ping https://somedomain.org
```

> ping: unknown host https://somedomain.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Wrapper Function

Write a function `ing` that deletes the leading protocol part and calls `ping` with the modified argument:

```
function ing { u=$1; shift; ping "$(echo "$u" | sed 's#^[httpsftp]\+://##; s#/$##')" $@; }
```

Put this in your `~/.bashrc` file and from now on you can always use `ing` instead of `ping` to ignore the protocoll part:

```
ing http://somedomain.org
```

(I use `ing` as function name, so I can easily edit the last line).

Answer (score 1):

#### Work around it

If you don't copy the whole URL but leave out the first character, you just have to enter:

```
ping <missing first character> CTRL-V
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Show the leading protocol in the URL bar

Go to your **Advanced Settings** in Firefox:

```
 `about:config`
```

Search for

```
browser.urlbar.trimURLs;false
```

And set this to `false`

Now you see the full URL again and don't copy the `http://` any more.

Source: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-show-the-full-url-in-firefox/